# Why D sharp not E flat in Turkish March

Tags: theory, piano, harmony, analysis

I'm analyzing Mozart's Turkish March piece for the piano.

As I see in measure 18 the harmony is F7 (fourth) with minor seven.

Assuming it is a minor seven because the harmony is F7 why they thought about the seventh as D sharp but not E flat ?

In other words:

Harmony is F7 --> includes Minor 7 --> should be E flat

See the picture (the measure in the middle)

[image: measure 18]

Comment: What key is it in again? Also note that E is notated in the next measure. While a natural sign wouldn't be strictly necessary in the next measure if Eb were used, it seems a bit clearer as written. Oh and E in the previous measure.

Comment: The key is A minor if anything.

Comment: For context, I believe [this](http://www.mutopiaproject.org/ftp/MozartWA/KV331/KV331_3_RondoAllaTurca/KV331_3_RondoAllaTurca-a4.pdf) is the sheet music.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a D# because it's functioning as a D#. In the three measures you can see the line goes E -> D# -> E. It's acting much more leading tone like than 7th like as if it were truly an F7 the next note would either be the same or resolve down.

The fact the harmony could be interpreted as an F7 is kind of a moot point as the next measure lands squarely on Am which harmonically doesn't make the most sense and could be a more chromatic harmony or exotic in nature which in that case a lot more needs to be looked into in this analysis.

Comment: That makes me think it might really be an augmented 6th instead of a minor 7th.

Comment: @ToddWilcox or Augmented 4th to Perfect 5th as the chord before and after seem to be Am and this could be an alteration. Without looking at the whole phrase it could be a lot of different things.

Comment: I agree that the D# functions as a leading tone and is therefore correct. I added the sheetmusic the OP is probably using in the comments section for analysis of the phrase.

Comment: It's a French 6th. The B in the descant is a chord tone, the top three notes make a truncated B dominant 7th chord (no fifth), the F in the bass moves to E.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Patrx2. This is a fairly clear example of a French augmented sixth (or Italian augmented sixth with a B passing tone, which to me is basically six of one, half a dozen the other). The only thing making it slightly less straightforward is that it doesn't proceed to as clear-cut of a V as it normally tends to. But it's still moving to a cadential 6/4 followed by an (admittedly somewhat mangled) V4/2.

Comment: @PatMuchmore, I'm saying French 6th here because Mozart is being _really_ cute. The first half of the bar is being voiced as if it were F7, but he's treating the high C as an appoggiatura with a cambiata-style resolution.

Comment: ...which is really cute because the C is consonant.

Comment: @user16935 is right. The C is part of the chord. The B is merely a passing note between the A and the next bar's C. So the chord is a [German sixth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_sixth_chord#German_sixth).

Answer (score 9):

To amplify Dom's reply, it is indeed a D♯. What is going on here is that Mozart is using an augmented sixth chord (specifically the French sixth) that is being used as dominant preparation. Normally how a French sixth works is that the upper notes form V<sup>7</sup> of V (with a missing fifth), while the bass falls a half step from ♭6 to 5. It is a variant of the Phrygian cadence (iv<sup>6</sup> - V).

Thus the progression would normally be F6 - V - i, but Mozart is being cute here: instead of holding the high B and heading directly to V, he is taking the chord through the tonic second inversion (which is normally treated as a suspension or appoggiatura leading to V, and is thus also dominant preparation) to the second inversion diminished seventh on G♯, which stands in for V.

Sure enough, in the following bar he ends up on i<sup>6</sup> (A minor). The B and A in the descant of the 2nd bar of your example are passing notes, the A being an accented one.